# How can I remember something for the duration of a desktop login session

Tags: javascript, linux, macos, unix, node.js

I'm writing a command-line program in Node (though will switch if another lang makes this easier) and it stores user data in an encrypted file. I want the user to give her password once during a desktop/ssh session and have it remembered until she logs out.

Presumably my script cannot modify environment variables so that they persist between invocations. How do programs like Keychain and sudo remember your password, and make sure to forget it on logout?

Comment: Since the person has logged in, you know for a fact he's authenticated no? Why should you try to remember the user & pass.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Sudo runs with setuid and is owned by root.  So any user that runs sudo will actually be running sudo as the root user.  From there, sudo (as root, on behalf of the user) checks the sudoers file (which is only readable by root) to see if the user is allowed to run sudo and what they can do.  If the user isn't in the sudoers file, then sudo exits and logs the attempt.  If the user is in the sudoers file, sudo asks for the user's password and checks it against what's in the shadow file (also only readable by root).  If it matches, sudo will record the access time in another file only readable by root and then execute the command.  Subsequent runs of sudo by that user within the timeout period don't prompt for a password, because sudo can check the time of its last record.  Sudo does not remember the user's password.

The key point is that, no matter what user runs it, sudo always runs as root and therefore can access files that only root can access.

Your application could mimic this behavior, I suppose, using a special user and a cache that is only permission-ed to that user.  It is important that you do not persist passwords.  Ever.

Another method that applications use, for example TrueCrypt, is to store the password in memory.  This method only works for applications (like TrueCrypt or even the operating system) that are always running.  As soon as the application closes, the "saved" password is lost.  This technique is [mostly secure](http://www.physorg.com/news122820185.html).

Hope this helps!